# Android ndk native app enviroment variable runtime

Tags: android, android-ndk, java-native-interface

Anybody know how could i set the PATH within the application that is calling native c++ code, which in terms uses system popen call to WGET and CURL etc...

I get permission denied setting the enviroment variable.

Reason why i need this as i don't want to call ./wget ... but directly wget ...

I have tried with normal putenv, getenv but it says permission denied. Or is there a permission that i could include. Or maybe some other way that popen calls have additional path set?

Thank you

Comment: It would be easy to understand if you could add code snippet to your question.

Comment: which part don't you understand ? There isn't any code? Just calling system(...) without specifying the full path. How to set PATH variable on Android without getting the permission denied